# respond_to? complains about nil is not a symbol

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm writing a CLI tool and have the following code:

```
commands = {
  :'-h' => :help,
  :'--help' => :help,
  :help => :help,
  :r => :remove,
  :rm => :remove,
  # ...
}

if some_obj.respond_to? commands[ARGV.first.to_sym]
  some_obj.send commands[ARGV.first.to_sym]
end
```

However, when `ARGV.first.to_sym` is not found in `commands`, `respond_to?` complains

```
./tool.rb:121:in `respond_to?': nil is not a symbol (TypeError)
        from ./tool.rb:121:in `<main>'
```

Is it possible to use some other approach without this error, and also without checking `nil` explicitly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An obvious fix is to check for presence of that command beforehand

```
if cmd = commands[ARGV.first.to_sym]
  if some_obj.respond_to? cmd
    some_obj.send cmd
  end
else
  # complain about unrecognized command
end
```

Yet better approach would be to use a tool built exactly for this kind of tasks, [OptionParser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html).

```
# example from the doc
options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: example.rb [options]"

  opts.on("-v", "--[no-]verbose", "Run verbosely") do |v|
    options[:verbose] = v
  end
end.parse!
```

### Update

`respond_to?` will also happily accept a string. So, for a quick fix do this:

```
if some_obj.respond_to? commands[ARGV.first.to_sym].to_s
  # ...
end
```

`nil.to_s` is empty string, and `respond_to?` will return `false` to that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I prefer `some_obj.some_magic_method nil` or something like that, since my code is much more complicated than the one posted in my question. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: See my update. But if I were you, I'd look into simplifying the code.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Sergio's answer (which is also good), you can use default value for the hash:

```
commands = Hash.new("").merge(
  :'-h' => :help,
  :'--help' => :help,
  :help => :help,
  :r => :remove,
  :rm => :remove,
  # ...
)
```

Then you don't need to check for `nil`.

```
commands[ARGV.first.to_sym]
.tap{|cmd| some_obj.send(cmd) if some_obj.respond_to?(cmd)}
```